# How to convert a column with a for loop and grep expressions?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of airbnb and one of the variables is amenities. The “amenities” column lists all the amenities provided by the host. What’s the total number of amenities oﬀered? Convert this to a numeric value that indicates the number of amenities provided. For example, if an instance of “amenities” is {TV,Internet,Wiﬁ,Washer}, it should convert to 4. Add this as a column to the dataframe. I am very confused on how to do this. Some of the amenities go up to 50 different amenities. Manually making vector would take forever.

I'm also confused on this as well for the airbnb dataset. Before we do any further analysis involving calculations, we should ﬁrst clean the data for mathematical operations. For example, the character “$” appears in the “price” column, making the data type of “price” character instead of numeric. Remove the “$” and “,” in this column and convert the data type as numeric (modify the raw data). I believe I have to use grep expressions.

Comment: A very simple way to count amenities would be to count the commas and add 1...

Answer (score 0):

if you have that info on a data frame you should try to use strsplit function:

```
sapply(strsplit(data.frame$amenities,","),length)
```

for subtitution of characters try gsub function

Comment: or `lengths(strsplit(...))`

Comment: I tried it and am getting an Error in strsplit(air$amenities, ",") : non-character argument